# Chrome REST Console "Connection Failed!"

Tags: google-chrome, asp.net-web-api

I have a simple test Web API that is up and working.  When I run it and enter `http://localhost:xxxxx/api/user` in the browser it returns a JSON empty array and it has full functionality when I test it with Fiddler.  But when I try and test it with the Chrome REST Console (with a GET Request to `http://localhost:xxxxx/api/user`) I get a "Connection Failed! Check your connectivity and try again" error.

Api Controller:

```
public class UserController : ApiController
{     
  private UserRepository repository = new UserRepository();

  public int Put(int id, [FromBody]int amount)
  { 
     var user = repository.GetByID(id);
     if (user == null) return -1;
     user.Total += amount;
     repository.Save(user);
     return user.Total;
   }

  public int Post([FromBody]CreateUserRequest request)
  { 
    var user = new User { Goal = request.Goal, Name = request.Name, Total = 0 };
    repository.Add(user);
    return user.UserId;
  }

  public IEnumerable<User> Get() { return new List<User>(repository.GetAll()); }

  public User Get(int id) {  var user = repository.GetByID(id); return user; }

  public class CreateUserRequest
  {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Goal { get; set; }
  }
```

The REST Console had formerly worked with this test Web API. The only reference I could find on the web referenced un-signed certificates.  I had created a signed certificate for localhost in IIS but I removed it, restarted the computer and the REST Console still returns the same error.  Not that that should matter since the Web API is running in IIS Express.  I have also tried it with other Web API's on my local machine and get the same error.

Does anyone have any idea as to the possible source of the problem or how I might troubleshoot it?  As I said the Web API's are fully function when tested with Fiddler.  The Web API was created with and is being ran from VS 2012 on a Windows 7 Ultimate workstation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I subsequently noticed that when ever I ran an app from Visual Studio in Chrome that it would redirect to https (even for apps that were not using SSL) and generate an SSL error.

I cleared all browsing data in Chrome and both the  Chrome and the REST Console problems cleared.